# Array to hold 6 whole numbers between 0-49

Tags: javascript

I am learning Javascript and need some code.

I need to hold 6 random numbers in an array between 0-49 and then display those numbers, how would I do this?

Comment: Did you try out something? Can you share it?

Comment: You spelt "I have some homework, can you do it please" wrong..

Comment: Yes, wait until we do your homework.

Comment: You can get code by writing it.

Comment: This is `!learning`!

Answer (score 1):

You use a pool with the numbers and draw 6.

```js
var pool = Array.apply(null, { length: 49 }).map(function (_, i) { return i + 1; }),
    numbers = Array.apply(null, { length: 6 }).map(function () { return pool[Math.floor(Math.random() * pool.length)]; });

console.log(numbers);
```